# jQuery Node.js and Socket.IO stop/start the SetInterval function in browser on click

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using `Node.js` and `Socket.IO`

All function can be run perfectly on browser.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://<?php echo $dAndonAccessDtl['IP_ADDRESS']; ?>:8080');
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
var lightbox = document.getElementById("light"); 
lightbox.addEventListener("change", function()
{
    socket.emit("light", Number(this.checked));

    $("#value").val(data);

    var value = $("#value").val();
    var total = $("#total").val();

    var grandtotal = parseInt(value) + parseInt(total);

    $("#total").val(grandtotal);

    var runningQty = $("#runningQty1").val();
$('.getIndicator').data('radialIndicator').animate(grandtotal).option('maxValue',parseInt(runningQty));
});
});
socket.on('light', function (data)
{
document.getElementById("light").checked = data;
socket.emit("light", data);

var cavity = $("#cavity1").val();

$("#value").val(data * cavity);

var value = $("#value").val();
var total = $("#total").val();

var grandtotal = parseInt(value) + parseInt(total);

$("#total").val(grandtotal);

var runningQty = $("#runningQty1").val();
var planID = $("#planID").val();

$('.getIndicator').data('radialIndicator').animate(grandtotal).option('maxValue',parseInt(runningQty));

if(data == 1)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveQuantity",
        data: 'planID=' + planID + '&quantity=' + data * cavity,
        success: function(msg)
        {
        }
    });
}
});
```

The current condition, the JS will run after page loaded on browser.

Now I need to control it when the JS should be run using button?

```
$('.startProduction').on('click', function()
{
$('.startProduction i').toggleClass('glyphicon-play glyphicon-pause');

var a = $('.startProduction i');
a.siblings().removeClass();
if(a.hasClass('active'))
{
    a.removeClass('active').toggleClass('inactive');
    //What function to stop the JS?
}
else
{
    a.removeClass('inactive').toggleClass('active');

    var socket = io.connect('http://<?php echo $dAndonAccessDtl['IP_ADDRESS']; ?>:8080');
    window.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
        var lightbox = document.getElementById("light"); 
        lightbox.addEventListener("change", function()
        {
            socket.emit("light", Number(this.checked));

            $("#value").val(data);

            var value = $("#value").val();
            var total = $("#total").val();

            var grandtotal = parseInt(value) + parseInt(total);

            $("#total").val(grandtotal);

            var runningQty = $("#runningQty1").val();

            $('.getIndicator').data('radialIndicator').animate(grandtotal).option('maxValue',parseInt(runningQty));
        });
    });
    socket.on('light', function (data)
    {
        document.getElementById("light").checked = data;
        socket.emit("light", data);

        var cavity = $("#cavity1").val();

        $("#value").val(data * cavity);

        var value = $("#value").val();
        var total = $("#total").val();

        var grandtotal = parseInt(value) + parseInt(total);

        $("#total").val(grandtotal);

        var runningQty = $("#runningQty1").val();
        var planID = $("#planID").val();

        $('.getIndicator').data('radialIndicator').animate(grandtotal).option('maxValue',parseInt(runningQty));

        if(data == 1)
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "saveQuantity",
                data: 'planID=' + planID + '&quantity=' + data * cavity,
                success: function(msg)
                {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
});
```

As you can see I set the JS will run after click button `.startProduction i`. Until this, it works.

But when I try to stop it (same click button), until this I don't know how to do that.

My question is it possible to stop the nodejs and socket.io set interval on browser? then back it again to start?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sure it can be done

//declare a Timer

var nrgstimer=[];

//Schedule a Timer

nrgstimer[socket.room]=setTimeout(function (){

```
 //Your code ...
```

},20000);

//delete a Timer

if(!isUndefinedVar(nrgstimer[socket.room])){

```
 clearTimeout(nrgstimer[socket.room]);
```

}